# Angular 5 - conditional required textarea

Tags: angular, textarea, required

If checkbox is clicked than textarea appears and is required **[required]="otherVendorsChecked == true ? true : false"**
If I select checkbox and than deselect it a textarea input is still required.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
<div>
    <mat-checkbox [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="otherVendorsChecked">Other option:</mat-checkbox>
</div>
<mat-form-field *ngIf="otherVendorsChecked == true">
    <textarea matInput formControlName="otherVendors" [required]="otherVendorsChecked == true ? true : false"></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

**[EDIT]**

If I remove ***ngIf="otherVendorsChecked == true"** than it works fine. 
I guess that **mat-form-field** is only removed with ngIf condition and therefore has no more influence to the required property.

This is my form in ngOnInit:

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
  otherVendors: new FormControl('', [Validators.minLength(2)]),
  ...
});
this.fillForm();
```

and in my fillForm I have this code:

```
this.form.controls['otherVendors'].setValue(this.lastFacilityDetailOfCalendarEvent.otherVendors);
    if(this.lastFacilityDetailOfCalendarEvent.otherVendors != null && this.lastFacilityDetailOfCalendarEvent.otherVendors.length > 0) {
      this.otherVendorsChecked = true;
    }
```

Comment: Have you initialized 'otherVendorsChecked' variable? If yes, Can I see it? I feel you are manipulating otherVendorsChecked variable somewhere in your .ts file.

Comment: If mat-form-field is removed with ngIf condition, there shouldn't be textarea at all. As Angular will remove mat-form-field complete node from HTML.

Comment: This was my opinion too - I don't know why it does not work.

Comment: Are you able to see textarea in HTML always? or Just  "otherVendors" Form control is required always?

Comment: I feel you might have made "otherVendors" Form control required while defining it using Validators or something like that. Eg., otherVendors = new FormControl(Validators.required).

Comment: no it disappears

Comment: Then I'm sure, "otherVendors" was made required somewhere in your .ts file, while creating react form using formGroups and formControls. I faced this once.

Comment: **otherVendors: new FormControl('', [Validators.minLength(2)]),** - I have defined it like this but made it not required.

Comment: Check my latest answer.

Answer (score 2):

**[Edited]**

Finally, After little bit of experimentation, I can see that it's all because of `<mat-form-field *ngIf="otherVendorsChecked == true">`.

Every time you change `otherVendorsChecked` value, FormControl will be toggled between *required* and *not required.* When `otherVendorsChecked` is true, your FormControl will be changed to required and but when `otherVendorsChecked` changed to false, Even before updating your FormControl to *not required* `*ngIf` will remove the textarea element from the DOM before triggering the change event of FormControl, so now FormControl has no idea to make it *not required*.

For a quick fix, Instead of using `*ngIf` You can just hide that section/element from view, maybe using `display: none;` or something like that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Check whether "otherVendorsChecked" is toggling between true and false state. Then proceed with your logic. I am seeing you are able to see the textarea always, since the "otherVendorsChecked" is true always.